# responsive axis values in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am building a graph with d3, sometimes the graph has smaller numbers on the axis and sometimes the graph has larger numbers on the axis. This causes the following problem from time to time;

[image]

Notice how at the left and right hand side the svg element is done and such the entire legend doesnt get displayed. I would prefer not to play around with increasing the margins on either side because that would decrease the screen real estate.

Is there a way such that the axis are responsive with regards to the data input? Ie; when the numbers are in the thousands then a 'k' or an 'm' is added to the number ( 100000 -> 100K, 12000000 -> 12M ).

Comment: why not create a rounding function with an if statement something like function rounder (x) { if (x<1000000) { d3.format(.0r) } else { d3.format(.2s) };.  Note I haven't tested this. btw there is the s type in the format function which rounds with unit suffixed like you want [(see this)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) allows you to do exactly that. The formats are described in the documentation for [`d3.format()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format). In your case, you need to specify something like

```
axis.tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```